# How to move to next page of results in Microsoft Graph Search API when searching calendar events?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

With Microsoft Graph API you can search your calendar events by issuing a request like it's [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/search-concept-events) or like this:

```
POST /v1.0/search/query HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 174

{
  "requests": [
    {
      "entityTypes": [
        "event"
      ],
      "query": {
        "queryString": "test"
      },
      "from": 0,
      "size": 50
    }
  ]
}
```

So, in my case, for the search query `test`, I have more than 200 events (recurring and single ones), and in the request payload we've sent to Microsoft Graph we have the `size` parameter which basically sets the limit of records to be returned by this call.

So, when I issue the request from above, I get something like this, but never more than `25` results. No matter how I modify the `size` parameter, it always returns `25` events, although there are hundreds.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json

{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#search",
  "value": [
  {
   "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.searchResponse",
   "searchTerms": [
    "contoso"
   ],
   "hitsContainers": [
    {
     "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.searchHitsContainer",
     "hits": [
      {
       "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.searchHit",
       "hitId": "AAMkADEwODY2NzllLTQ3MmEtNGRlMC05ZTUyLTE4ZDRhYmU1ZGM3NABGAAAAAAA3+iYQBnJnQabRVDelNhnzBwAejhWkAOAxQ6M4c1c9NwfrAAAAAAENAAAejhWkAOAxQ6M4c1c9NwfrAABbUZLJAAA=",
       "rank": 1,
       "summary": "this is a testing nothing more",
       "resource": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.event",
        "end": {
         "dateTime": "2020-06-16T04:15:00Z",
         "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "hasAttachments": false,
        "iCalUId": "040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E008000000007093FDD79B3AD60100000000000000001000000036DAA2262EB4E04DA27DA77985FB8251",
        "isAllDay": false,
        "sensitivity": "Normal",
        "start": {
         "dateTime": "2020-06-16T03:30:00Z",
         "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "subject": "testing testing 123",
        "type": "Single"
       }
      }
     ],
     "total": 25,
     "moreResultsAvailable": true
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Furthermore, in the response you get the flag `moreResultsAvailable` which is in my case `true`, but other than that, I can't find a way to traverse between the results page, or do pagination of some sort.

What am I missing here, or in the docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, when I issue the request from above, I get something like this,
> but never more than 25 results. No matter how I modify the size
> parameter, it always returns 25 events, although there are hundreds.

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/search-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0#page-search-results

> The maximum results per page (size) is 25 for message and event.

For paging you just need to use the from property to specify the start of the page eg for the next page it would be

```html
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "entityTypes": [
        "event"
      ],
      "query": {
        "queryString": "test"
      },
      "from": 25,
      "size": 25
    }
  ]
}
```